# How to fetch polygons from PostGIS into a PHP array?

Tags: postgis, polygon, sql, php, array

Currently I fetch polygons from a database table using `ST_AsText()`. The results are in text format, like this:

```
POLYGON((84 104,212 48,321 122,243 179,275 238,131 240,84 104))
```

I am not quite sure if `ST_AsText()` and string manipulation is the way to go for good performance. Is there another way to fetch the points?

How can I get all points of a polygon as an array in PHP?

Comment: JSON might be a better solution http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html is fast with openlayers

Comment: Thanks, that is a great option since I can directly forward that to Leaflet. If you would write an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Posted a longer answer basis on @danijar feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For current method `ST_AsText()` I suggest that you request `GeoJSON` instead this can be requested from PostGIS natively

Example:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom) from fe_edges limit 1;
                       st_asgeojson
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-89.734634999999997,31.492072000000000],
[-89.734955999999997,31.492237999999997]]]}
(1 row)
--3d point

SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON('LINESTRING(1 2 3, 4 5 6)');

st_asgeojson
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]}
```

in response to  JSON might be a better solution ST_AsGeoJSON is fast with openlayers

Full official documentation:
http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html

Comment: I have one related question. It there some kind of reverse function? Would be really helpful if I could store from JSON by something like `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON()`.

Comment: http://postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html will take GeoJSON and import it into PostGIS